# Getting java.util.InputMismatch upon typing "exit"

Tags: java, string, integer

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit the program");
    System.out.println("Enter the search key: ");

    int searchkey = input.nextInt();
    String exit = input.nextLine();

    while (!exit.equals("exit"))
    {

        linear(array, searchkey);
        binary(array,searchkey);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter exit to end the program");
        System.out.println("Enter the search key: ");

        searchkey = input.nextInt();
        exit = input.nextLine();

    }
```

I am getting an InputMismatch exception. I know this is because of `searchkey`. How can I use the string to exit the program?

Comment: I am sorry if forgot to change the println statement to " Enter exit to end the program"

Answer (score 2):

If "exit" is the first thing you type when you run the program then you will crash. This is because the first read in of the input is `input.nextInt()`. If you type "exit" and `input` expects an int, it will throw the `InputMismatch` exception.

To correct for this, you can use `input.next()` if you dont know what you are going to get. Then you can do your own parsing on the input.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling nextInt without checking it is an int. You need to check hasNextInt() first because they might have typed "exit" as you instructed.

Comment: @user2840592 use an `if` test to see whether you have a number or not.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you type "exit" immediately after the print statement, so it gets captured by

```
     searchkey= input.nextInt();
```

If `nextInt()`gets a non-`int` passed to it, it will cause an exception.

Comment: yes , i know what is wrong, how do i do that so the user can enter both

Answer (score 1):

`input.nextInt()` expects you to enter an integer (like -1, 0, 1, 2..) If you introduce "exit" then it will throw that exception.

Maybe if you change the position of your prompt and your instructions?

```
    System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit the program");
    int searchkey= input.nextInt(); // Only integers are allowed 

    System.out.println("Enter the search key: ");
    String exit = input.nextLine(); //Introduce any string, like exit or apples.
```

System.out.println will not know what you are going to do, that is something that is meaningful for you, no for the program itself.

```
This is your current output: 
Enter -1 to exit the program
Enter the search key: 
<here you should type an integer and enter>
<here you should type a String>
```

It seems that you don't need the integer at all, but a proper output ought be:

```
Enter -1 to exit the program
<here you should type an integer and enter>
Enter the search key: 
<here you should type a String>
```

After calling nextInt or nextLine, your console will stop printing until you enter something. If you enter "exit" when nextInt was called you will get that exception, just try to do the math "exit"+5.

Comment: i am soo sorry i forgot to change the println statement "Enter -1 to exit the program" to " Enter exit to end the program"